# Random Image Gallery with json?

Tags: javascript, json, random, image-gallery

I'm trying to make an infinity scroll of random images with a json file. I succeeded, the problem is, this should work without any server. 
 
So I was trying to put all the information in a 'var' but now these images are not loading anymore. 
Is there a way to fix it without needing a server? 
Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>

    </main>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <button onclick="setTimeout(getData,2000); return false" type="submit" id="button" value="Load more" class="button">
                    Load more</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
</body>
```

Everything, that is now written in var imgJson, was in images.txt. 
Now, I've seen other people write it in a var, so I did that, but it doesn't work. 
To be fair, I just learned about JSON, yesterday, so I'm pretty new to it.

JS:

```
// const URL = "images/images.txt"
var imgJson = {"items":[{
    "id": 1,
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300'
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/201\/301'
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/202\/302'
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/203\/303'
}
]}

getData();

function getData(){

    let main = document.querySelector("main");
    console.log("fetch some data");
    fetch(imgJson)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        data.items.forEach(item => {
            let fig = document.createElement("figure");
            let img = document.createElement("img");    
            img.src = item.img;

            fig.appendChild(img);
            main.appendChild(fig);
        });
    });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("active");

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".button").removeClass("active");
        },2000);
    });
});
```

CSS (only the part with the image-part):

```
main {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 1rem;
        width: 80vw;
        margin: auto;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
      }


main figcaption {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
}
main img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You don't have to `fetch` the JSON. Fetching is basically downloading or uploading. Just loop over the`imgJson` var and you are good to go.

Comment: This is not causing a problem, but you don't have to escape forward slashes in your JS objects. e.g. `https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to `.fetch()` the variable `imgJson`, it's just a JavaScript `Object`. You can just loop through `Objects` and `Arrays` with JavaScript.

```js
// const URL = "images/images.txt"
var imgJson = {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300'
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/201\/301'
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/202\/302'
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/203\/303'
    }
  ]
}

getData();

function getData() {

  let main = document.querySelector("main");
  console.log("fetch some data");
  imgJson.items.forEach(item => {
    let fig = document.createElement("figure");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = item.img;

    fig.appendChild(img);
    main.appendChild(fig);
  });
}
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

main figcaption {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
}

main img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
</main>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button onclick="setTimeout(getData,2000); return false" type="submit" id="button" value="Load more" class="button">Load more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I noticed you have a `setTimeout` function which isn't necessary. I will show you a method with `Promises`. Because it makes the code asynchronous aswell. And it will send something back as soon as all images are appended.

There is no need to `.fetch()` the variable `imgJson`, it's just a JavaScript `Object`. You can just loop through `Objects` and `Arrays` with JavaScript.

```js
// const URL = "images/images.txt"
var imgJson = {
  "items": [{
      "id": 1,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300'
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/201\/301'
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/202\/302'
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/203\/303'
    }
  ]
}

getData().then(a => console.log(a));

function getData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let main = document.querySelector("main");
    console.log("fetch some data");
    imgJson.items.forEach(item => {
      let fig = document.createElement("figure");
      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = item.img;

      fig.appendChild(img);
      main.appendChild(fig);
    });
    resolve('done');
  });
}
```

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

main figcaption {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
}

main img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
</main>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button onclick="getData().then(a => console.log(a))" type="submit" id="button" value="Load more" class="button">Load more</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Didn't know it was that simple

Comment: I added another example (without `setTimeout`, but asynchronously with Promises). It will send you a message back as soon as the Promise is resolved. This might be helpful to you aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button which replaces the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element, with a different image each time, then you can view my JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0a2s6pg/

Otherwise, here is a code snippet:

```js
var imgJson = {"items":[{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/200\/300'
}, {
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/201\/301'
},
{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/202\/302'
},
{
    "img": 'https:\/\/picsum.photos\/203\/303'
}
]}

var amount = 0
document.getElementById('imageBtn').onclick = function () {
    console.log("Replacing image...");
    document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", imgJson.items[amount].img);
    console.log(amount);
    if (amount == 3) {
        amount = 0;
    } else {
        amount++;
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://picsum.photos/203/303" style="display: block;">
<button id="imageBtn" style="margin-top: 10px;">Random image</button>
```